# Auto call a php function every 10 seconds

Tags: php, jquery, function, call

I have a function that reads certain elements from a file that is updated nearly every second. I am trying to find a way to auto call the function so it re-prints that information every ten seconds.

What is the best way to do this? I tried some javascript but I could not get it to work. All help is appreciated.

Comment: `setTimeout` or `setInterval` combined with `$.ajax()`. What did you try?

Comment: Look at [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [Webworkers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) along with `setInterval`

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: setInterval. I may have messed up the syntax...how can you call a PHP function from a javascript?

Comment: Just like you would call any other server-side script.

Comment: You're wanting to call from the client-side or server side? Show us what a single call to the function looks like.

Comment: @user2537383 You can't, you'll have to make an ajax request to do that.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have direct access to your php functions, but you can use ajax to call a php script. If you're unfamiliar with how to use ajax, see here: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: `<script>
    var nIntervId;
 
    function updateInfo() {
 nIntervId = setInterval(<?php getInfo() ?>, 500);
    }
</script>`

Comment: Yeah, you can't do that. See the page I linked for information on ajax.

Comment: PHP is run right before the page is loaded. It is not like javascript and can not be run on demand(ex: if you press a button). I would recommend using something like Ajax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to put it in a function and call it again when it's finish.

```
function ajaxCall() {
   $.ajax({
      ...
   }.always(function() {
      setTimeout(ajaxCall, 10000); // 10 seconds
   });
}

ajaxCall();
```

**EDIT**

Updated due to roasted comment.

Comment: `setTimeout(ajaxCall, 10000);` and you should use always() IMO